# How to use ethereumjs-tx | Without getting errors: Tx is not a constructor?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

I am trying to include etheruemjs-tx browser build, to work with it on my browser for signing transactions. It keeps on throwing an error "Tx is not a constructor"

```
const Tx = "https://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/blob/master/dist/ethereumjs-tx/ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3.js";
```

On my terminal all is working fine, because I just used

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
```

but since I can not use require() on my javascript code, I have been trying all sorts of methods and I am failing to get it work. On my browser console after clicking the button it goes to this line..

```
const tx = new Tx(txObject,{chain: 'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'})
```

The error is:

> (index):368 Uncaught TypeError: Tx is not a constructor

Help on how to use ethereumjs-tx in a browser will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version you should change:

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
```

to

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
```